# First error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY

Tags: trigger, dml

Use-case: Trying to update a text field after an insert. Also trying to get the Record Name field(text field) to a specific format using another auto generated field and a picklist field.

Simple trigger:

```
trigger customTrigger on Custom_obj__c (after insert, after update) {
customTriggerHelper helper = new customTriggerHelper();

if(Trigger.isInsert){
    if(Trigger.isAfter){
        helper.updateROField(Trigger.New);
    }
}

if(Trigger.isAfter){
    if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        helper.updateNameField(Trigger.New);
    }
  }
}
```

Helper class:

```
public class customTriggerHelper {
public void updateROField(List<Custom_obj__c> records){

    //List<Custom_obj__c> toUpdateList = new List<Custom_obj__c>();
    Custom_obj__c record = [Select Id, Name, harField__c From Custom_obj__c Where ID In : records Order By CreatedDate Desc LIMIT 1];

    if(record.harField__c == NULL){
        System.debug('Inside updateROField method');
        record.harField__c = record.Name;
        update record;
    }
}

public void updateNameField(List<Custom_obj__c> records){

    //List<Custom_obj__c> toUpdateList = new List<Custom_obj__c>();
    Custom_obj__c record = [Select Id, Name, AutoGenerateField__c, harField__c, pickList__c From Custom_obj__c Where ID In : records Order By CreatedDate Desc LIMIT 1];

    if(record.harField__c != '' && record.AutoGenerateField__c != '' && record.pickList__c != ''){
        System.debug('Inside updateNameField method');
        String picklistVal = record.pickList__c;
        String firstFourChars = picklistVal.substring(0,4);
        String concat = firstFourChars + ' - ' + record.AutoGenerateField__c;
        record.Name = concat;
        update record;
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

> execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a09f4000006fXAfWWe; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, customTrigger: maximum trigger depth exceeded Custom_obj__c

What am I doing wrong here? Looks pretty simple and straightforward, but I am unable to move forward.

Comment: Taking a quick look, it seems you don't have the `harField` field in your SOQL. Additionally you may like to verify if the FLS on the field is appropriate and that it can be updated.

Comment: I would add that `harField` does not look like a correct Salesforce Field name.

Comment: @JayantDas Yes, I do have the `harField` in my SOQL. Also I do have edit access to that field.

Comment: @SebastianKessel Sure, its a custom field.

Comment: What's the rest of the stack trace after `CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY`?

Comment: @DavidReed `CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, customTrigger: maximum trigger depth exceeded Custom_obj__c`

Comment: @AustinEvans is Name a Austonumber field? or normal text field?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal 'Name' is a text field itself.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use After Insert /Update trigger to update the record in whose context the trigger is run. You can alter those values in Before trigger.

Thus your trigger will be:

```
trigger customTrigger on Custom_obj__c (before insert, before update) {
customTriggerHelper helper = new customTriggerHelper();

if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
    if(Trigger.isBefore){
        helper.updateROFieldAndName(Trigger.New);
    }
}


}
```

Also your handler code:

```
public class customTriggerHelper {

    public void updateROFieldAndName(List<Custom_obj__c> records){

        for(Custom_obj__c rec : List<Custom_obj__c> records){

                rec.harField__c = record.Name;
                if(String.isNotBlank(rec.AutoGenerateField__c) && String.isNotBlank(rec.pickList__c)){
                    record.harField__c = record.Name ;
                    record.Name = rec.pickList__c.substring(0,4) + '-' + record.AutoGenerateField__c;
            }

        }

    }   

 }
```

Comment: This helps me with the error message. But how can I get my two requirements fire with this? 1. Updating the `harField__c` field. 2. Updating Record Name field with the specific format?

Basically I am trying to capture the Record Name field in `harField__c` prior to this field getting updated to a new specific format. Thoughts?

Comment: @AustinEvans
You wanna store old value of Name in harField__c?

Comment: Yes, like whenever the user inputs a value in the Record Name field, I am trying to store it in a field and prior to commiting to the database, I am trying to update the Record Name field with a specific format.

Comment: So if I understand it rightly, User enter Name field as well as harField__c,

You populate the Name field in some format and backup the Name field in harField__c field?

Comment: Use would only enter Name field. Then name field will be formatted to a specific format and the harField will be populated with the old Name field(entered by user).

Comment: @AustinEvans Updated code for method updateNameField field to represent the swap of Name in harfield...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85762/discussion-between-austin-evans-and-pranay-jaiswal).